# Passar valor de propriedades iguais, classes diferentes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Preciso do seguinte não sei se tem como fazer, Por isso a pergunta, eu tenho duas **classes** e nestas duas classes eu possuo propriedades exatamente iguais, como segue os exemplos:

```
public class Cliente
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FisicaJuridica { get; set; }
    public string NomeRazaoSocial { get; set; }
    public string ApelidoNomeFantasia { get; set; }
    public string CPFCNPJ { get; set; }
}

public class Fornecedor
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FisicaJuridica { get; set; }
    public string NomeRazaoSocial { get; set; }
    public string ApelidoNomeFantasia { get; set; }
    public string CPFCNPJ { get; set; }
}
```

O que eu precisava fazer seria algo como por exemplo:

```
var cliente = ctx.Clientes.Find(01);//Preenche o objeto cliente
var fornecedor = cliente;//Seria algo assim mas sei que é impossivel
```

O que eu precisava, ao tentar o metodo acima onde eu atribua o cliente ao fornecedor as propriedas com o mesmo nome recebessem os valores da cliente, tipo:

```
fornecedor.FisicaJuridica = cliente.FisicaJuridica;
```

Preciso só saber se é possivel, Ou uma melhor forma de eu fazer isso, Sem ter de ir proprieda por propriedade e atribuindo os valores, As classes acima são só exemplos as reais são gigantes, daria muito trabalho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não dá pra igualar objetos de tipos diferentes diretamente assim, a não ser que implementassem uma mesma interface.

Uma sugestão é fazer por reflexion, ou ainda usar um mapeador, como AutoMapper: [AutoMapper.org](http://automapper.org/)

Com o AutoMapper você pode passar os valores de propriedade com mesmo nome e tipo de um objeto para outro de forma bem simples, e ainda pode implementar manualmente como seria a "transformações" de propriedade com valores semelhantes, mas com nomes/tipos diferentes.

Veja um exemplo de código para o seu caso, que seria algo como:

```
var cliente = ctx.Clientes.Find(01);
Mapper.CreateMap(typeof(Cliente), typeof(Fornecedor));
var fornecedor= Mapper.Map<Cliente, Fornecedor>(cliente);
```

Aqui tem um exemplo de como configurar o AutoMapper: [Configurando AutoMapper](http://www.eduardopires.net.br/2013/08/asp-net-mvc-utilizando-automapper-com-view-model-pattern/)